# Can't refer to environment variable inside Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I set environment variables but can't refer to them inside cloud function.
What I did is like this.

```
firebase functions:config:set myproject.id=projectid1234 myproject.location=us-central1
```

And I saw the variables are actually set.

```
{
  "myproject": {
    "location": "us-central1",
    "id": "projectid1234"
  }
}
```

And my function is like this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) {
    const projectId = functions.config().myproject.id

    ...
})
```

And error log

> Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

What am I wrong with this? The variables I set are the project's id and the project's location.

Comment: Did you redeploy your Cloud Functions to make the new configuration available?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Ah that's the cause of the error.. I set the variable first and then deployed the function.. Thanks it works now.

Comment: Glad I could help you. I've written an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), you need to redeploy your Cloud Functions to make the new configuration available.

Comment: This helped me get it working once I deployed the function, but it still wasn't working when running the function locally during development. Finally figured out to get it working locally you have to run this from your functions directory on your local workspace:  

`firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`

See [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/264) and [this firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)